# Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform

So I am running stripe payment method in my code and it produces the error `index.cjs.js:409 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

I had allowed permission and upgraded my plan to blaze plan on firebase to allow stripe connectivity, but it still gives me the error... Anyone have any suggestions?
Here is my firebase rules :

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /environments/{environment}/companies/{userId} {
      allow write, read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      match /{anySubCollection}/{anyDocument} {
        allow write, read: if request.auth.uid == userId;  
    
      }
    match /customers/{uid} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == uid;

      match /checkout_sessions/{id} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
      }
      match /subscriptions/{id} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid == uid;
      }
    }

    match /products/{id} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if false;

      match /prices/{id} {
        allow read: if true;
        allow write : if false;
      }

      match /tax_rates/{id} {
        allow read: if true;
      }
    
    }
 }}}
```

this is the code In which I try to access the docs and write my actual code in:

```
 import firebase from 'firebase'
import getStripe from './stripe'

const firestore = firebase.firestore();

export async function createCheckoutSession(){
    // return firestore.collection()
    const checkoutSessionRef =  await firestore.collection('testdata').doc().collection('checkout_sessions').add(
        
        {price : price here
         success_url : window.location.origin,
         cancel_url: window.location.origin,
    }
    );

    checkoutSessionRef.onSnapshot(async (snap) => {
        const {sessionid} = snap.data();
        if (sessionid) {
             const stripe = await getStripe()
             stripe.redirectToCheckout({sessionid})
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code which is trying to access the document or collection?

Comment: @NicholasTower just edited my question :)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not really what i'm looking for. That code is initializing firebase, but not using it. I'm looking for something like `db.collection('foo').doc('bar').set(someObject)`. Basically, i'm trying to find out which one of your firestore rules is the one that matters, and that depends on the code where you try to set or get a value.

Comment: @NicholasTower just edited again, this what you mean?

Comment: Yes it is, thanks.

Comment: @NicholasTower okay great... any chance you can tell what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Your rules don't have any entry that match the collection named "testdata". The default behavior if there is no match is to deny access, which is why you're getting an error.

I think you may have some misplaced curly brackets in your rules. You've set it up so that everything is nested inside the rule for `match /environments/{environment}/companies/{userId} {`. I think you meant to close that rule before the rule for "customers".

Even fixing that though, there's still no entry for "testdata", so you'll need to add that in. For example:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /environments/{environment}/companies/{userId} {
      allow write, read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      match /{anySubCollection}/{anyDocument} {
        allow write, read: if request.auth.uid == userId; 
      }
    }
      
    match /testdata/{uid} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == uid;

      match /checkout_sessions/{id} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
      }
    }

    // ..
  }
}
```

Alternatively, maybe what you meant to access was the "customers" collection. In that case, you don't need to change your rules (other than the closing bracket), you need to change your code:

```
const checkoutSessionRef =  await firestore.collection('customers').doc().collection('checkout_sessions').add(
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit Rules of Cloud Firestore to this code then submit publish button

This is the code

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```